# How can i change all color with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace all `#111` color (example color) with `#222` (new color) in html file using jQuery. I want to do this to change the theme of website by single click.

**Initial css:**

```
body{
    bg-color:#111;
    color:#111;
}
div1{
    bg-color:#111;
    color:#111;
}
.
.
.
divn{
    bg-color:#111;
    color:#111;
}
```

**After click event:**

```
body{
    bg-color:#222;
    color:#222;
}
div1{
    bg-color:#222;
    color:#222;
}
.
.
.
divn{
    bg-color:#222;
    color:#222;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

The best solution here is to define 2 css classes with cascaded styles to nested elements.

```
body { color:#111 }
.theme1 { color: #222; }
.theme2 { color: #333; }
.theme2 a { color: #003366; }
...
```

Then you can change the css class of your `body` element and all elements on the page will inherit new styles.

```
// theme1 color
<body class="theme1">
...
</body>

// theme2 color
<body class="theme2">
...
</body>
```

jquery code:

```
$('body').addClass('theme1');
```

Comment: i cant do this .I want to do this for a firefox plugin

Comment: so your FF plugin probably have some parent element. Change the css class for this parent element in the same way like I described for `body`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to change theme with one click is give some class to your body tag.

Then in your css:

```
body{ color: #111;}
body.secondTheme{color : #222; }
```

And you can bind change it for click event in jquery

```
$("#yourButton").click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("secondTheme");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the proper way to do this would be to assign a css class to every html element you want to change color.

HTML:

```
<div class="colorChange">
```

CSS:

```
.colorChange{ color:#111;}
```

Then you would have a button that triggers a javascript function, which would change the color attribute of the colorChange class, I would recommend using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(".colorChange").css('color', '#222');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can toggle between classes I think it will be better; if you can't/don't want you can use the `.filter` function in jQuery:

```
$('yourselector').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('color')=='rgb(0, 1, 17)';
}).css('color','rgb(0, 2, 34)');
```

This will change all elements selected by `yourselector` with color `rgb(0, 1, 17)` to color `rgb(0, 2, 34)`.

Obviously you can also do the same with other css attributes.